# can not access data header in build version of angular 10

Tags: node.js, angular, httprequest, httpresponse

here my header of code in http request:

```
    return this.http.post<any>(this.path.userRoot + '/logIn/random', body,
        {
            withCredentials: true,
            responseType: "json",
            observe: 'response'
        }
    )
        .pipe(map(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('auth-token', response.headers.get('auth-token'));
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.body.message));
                this.userSubject.next(response.body.message);
            }
            return response;
        }));
```

after run, the value of "response.headers.get('auth-token')" is null.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using cors?

Comment: hi, Yes, I use it

Comment: Show some backend code. It looks like you don't expose the header

Comment: yes it is solved after add this header , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use CORS, then you need to specify the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)) server side.

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: auth-token, OtherCustomHeader
```